# What is the advantage of separate line and fill layers in grease pencil?

Tags: workflow, grease-pencil

The default 2D animation setup starts with one layer for "Lines" and one for "Fills". This feels like a traditional 2D setup where fills are behind the lines. However, it is also possible to use materials which are both stroked and filled, which achieves the same (?) result.

What are the advantages of the separate layer for fills? What are the disadvantages of using materials with both "fill" and "stroke" enabled?

Comment: Hello. I use separate layers and use separate materials as I like the additional control. I like to detail with a plain stroke and fill on the layer below. Using the fill on the same layer thins your strokes so it really needs to be on a lower layer. As you mention you can setup a stroke with a fill but that's only really useful when drawing closed shapes. Drawing unusual shapes can cause some freak results I find. Its also important to remember Blender layers items on 1 layer by the order they were drawn so the last fill then stroke will overlap previous strokes which for me is undesirable.

Comment: Good question. I never ever use materials with both fill and stroke enabled so to me a toggle switch would be just as good. But maybe the devs thought there could be cases where it's useful so left it up to the user?